# Entry minus sign in a TextField with TextArea.DECIMAL in IOS

Tags: codenameone

I define a texfield with TextArea.DECIMAL and want to entry decimal(1.21  -0.32 11.00).
The numberic pad doesn't include minus(-) in iOS.
How do I set the attribut of a TextField to enter minus number (numberic pad include a minus sign(-))?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remember this was asked in the past but I can't find the answers. I think it's possible that this works for `NUMERIC` when running on iOS despite the fact that the docs say that it's for integers only.

This is an inherent problem in iOS as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613109/uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-with-negative-numbers). It can probably be fixed by integrating the toolbar suggestion mentioned in the answers into our keyboard code [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/CodenameOne_GLViewController.m#L441).

Comment: It seems complicated.

Comment: Just using numeric isn't complicated. Most of the work for supporting negative numbers in the iOS native toolbar is already done. You can file an issue with the content of this answer. It should be a relatively easy fix.

Comment: I don't quite understand where to file an issue. And how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Issues are always filed [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/). If you do want to fix it you can fork the project to submit a PR. The Objective-C method I listed includes a large set of if statements that checks the type of field we're dealing with. One of the options is "decimal". In that block we have code that sometimes adds a "Done" button (dealing with a different iOS issue). This code is very similar to the `+/-` option in the answer I linked. That workaround can be integrated into that block too.